# How to parse and format an integer with zero decimal places in GWT?

Tags: gwt, localization, internationalization

Using GWT [NumberFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/NumberFormat.html), I need to have a decimal format that basically accepts no decimal point character and zero decimal places. For example, 123 should be valid but 123.4 and 123.9 should be rejected. Also, rounding of decimal values into nearest integer is not an option.
I thought the following would work, but it does not:

```
double val = NumberFormat.getFormat("#0").parse(str);
```

I definitely need it to support GWT i18n formatting, such as "," separators for large numbers. The input "str" is for example the argument coming to a [Parser.parse(text)](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/text/shared/Parser.html#parse%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, similar to the one in [IntegerParser](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/text/client/IntegerParser.html). IntegerParser does not validate zero decimal places properly and only rounds the value rather than rejecting numbers with decimal point.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use [IntegerParser](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/text/client/IntegerParser.html).

It uses the following method under the covers:

```
(int) Math.rint(NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat().parse(object.toString()));
```

UPDATE:

Also, you can use [LongBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/LongBox.html) instead of TextBox.

Comment: It does not work! Surprisingly, it seems "minimumFractionDigits" parameter is only respected in format(number) methods and NOT parse(string) ones.

Comment: Sorry, this one does not work either because it accepts values such as 14.9 and returns 15! I need an error/exception for values like 14.9 etc.

Comment: How do you get your String?

Comment: Are your strings coming from a file, or from a TextBox?

Comment: A TextBox. What difference does it make?

Comment: It really helps when you explain your use case :) I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks but I have mentioned IntegerParser in my question. It does not validate properly and only rounds decimal points.

Answer (score 0):

The way I finally solved my problem was by explicitly looking for decimal separator in the input string before trying to parse it using NumberFormat. Here is the code:

```
final String DECIMAL_SEPARATOR =
    LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getNumberConstants().decimalSeparator();
if (str.contains(DECIMAL_SEPARATOR))
        throw new ParseException("Invalid integer value (" + str + ")", 0);
return (int) Math.rint(NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat().parse(str));
```

I am still interested in finding a better way to do it using NumberFormat.